# Matched Case Control Design - Selecting Analysis

Tags: regression

I am working through a data analysis plan for a program eval project. We are planning to use a matched case control design. We will be comparing involvement in a program versus going to jail (the traditional pathway) and comparing recidivism rates. People will enter the program in different cohorts and will be in the program for a year. so the critical needs are to be able to account for time spent in jail, time in the program, and length and severity of prior offense history. What is the best approach? I've seen people suggest Cox Regression, Bayesian Regression, Cochran-Mantel-Haenszel Estimates, etc. What would you suggest?

Thanks!

Kaitlyn

Answer (score 0):

Since the nature of the outcome is recidivism, i.e. a time-to-event variable, the Cox regression would be a more powerful analysis for unmatched data than logistic regression even if there is no censoring. And by my reckoning, we would anticipate the censoring or attrition rate to be quite high, informative censoring even a possiblilty.

You have proposed "matching" as a way to identify an analysis set with a balanced distribution of highly prognostic variables that are probably associated with the penalty-type (jail, versus program) as well: we are all assuming this is a non-randomized design.

Matching and covariate adjustment essentially achieve the same purpose. To attempt to ensure that the residuals are independent of the predictor(s) and the outcome. In a conditional analysis (like a T-test) you can imagine that the residuals from within a matched set have been "subtracted" from one another, like in the paired t-test, so that all the common variables within the set are effectively adjusted for. When you have, as in your case, a handful of variables, creating a matched set typically adds no extra value compared to a flexible adjustment for those variables. Just as with adjustment, what remains is all the other variables *not* included in the analysis as possible lurking factors.

In this case I would propose a Cox proportional-hazards analysis.

"Bayesian regression" is essentially meaningless unless you intend to invoke the informative prior. Bayesian analogues of GLMs provide roughly the same estimation, inference, and predictions, it all boils down to interpretation where the Bayesian interpretation of model results is different from frequentist.